# Netbeans glassfish auto deploy

Tags: maven, deployment, netbeans, glassfish

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hot deploying changes with Netbeans, Maven, and Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290935/hot-deploying-changes-with-netbeans-maven-and-glassfish)

I am working in netbeans using Glassfish as the server. Every time I make changes in js pages, I have to build the project using maven and redeploy it and then run it. I am at Windows, so this process takes about 10 mins each time.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: As you can see in the title, I was talking about auto-deploy. The details are in the content. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel) might be an option - it can update static resources as well as it handles Java code changes